# How to count the appearances of a string within a string?

Tags: c, string, pointers, strstr

I have to count the appearances of a specific C string within a bigger one. I am using strstr() function to count and advance with a char pointer through the big C string. The problem is that it seems to count too little, like the reduction of the text is increasing to fast, jumping over big chunks of characters. I am using  a type int variable, called 'x', to 'reduce' text from left to right, but I don't know were is the problem with assigning its new value.

```
int x=0;
while((p=strstr(text+x,triG))!=NULL)
{
    v[i]++;
    x+=x+3+(p-(text+x));
}
```

text is of type char*, dynamically alocated. triG is of type char[4], and p is of type char*.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the content of `text` and `triG` besides the maximum lenght of `triG`? Do you need to find for example all occurrences of "aaa" in "aaaaaaaaaa"? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You're increasing the value of x by too much after each match.

```
int x=0;
while((p=strstr(text+x,triG))!=NULL)
{
    v[i]++;
    x = p - text + strlen(triG);
}
```

You can also simplify the calculation of `x`.  You were both adding and removing `x` - these cancel out.  Its also a bit more flexible to use `strlen(triG)` rather than hard-coding the assumption it'll always be 4.

Comment: Thank you so much...It's seems so silly to me now. To much debugging over C code, I guess. A wish you all a nice day:D

Comment: @IonutGoldan Glad this has helped.  If you're satisfied with this as an answer, can you consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it?

Answer (score 1):

you have

```
x+=x+...
```

you should have either

```
x = x+...
```

or

```
x += ...
```